# ngClass - vs - [attr.class] - vs - class | will attribute interpolation be deprecated and how to make this performant

Tags: angular, interpolation

I would like a class set once when the template initializes. A colleague wrote

```
<div [attr.class]="localVariable === 'string' ? 'class-name' : null"><div>
```

but this seems odd. I think I wouldn't want

```
[ngClass]="{'class-name': localVariable === 'string'}"
```

because this would run every life cycle, and I don't expect the `localVariable` to change dynamically during the application execution.

I prefer instead:

```
class="{{localVariable === 'string' ? 'class-name' : null}}"
```

but my colleague said that this is not advised by Angular, and that support for interpolation on attribute will be deprecated. Can anyone confirm this or make a case for which is these most performant given that the bound value is not expected to change after the template renders?

Comment: Inside `[ngClass]` you don't need the double braces. You can simply write: `[ngClass]="{'className': localVariable === 'string'}"`

Comment: ah, yes, syntax error on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ngClass` you can add classes dynamically to the current classes list for that element. But when you use `attr.class` it entirely reassigns the list of classes acting on that element. You can have `class` along with `ngClass` in an element where `ngClass` will contain the dynamic list of classes. More on ngClass [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#how-to-use).